# NSURLSession().dataTaskWithRequest(...) can't throw?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I have this function that takes care of an API call (`makeAPICall`) that I'd like to throw an error for certain API responses and when the `httpResponse.statusCode != 200`.
The problem is that, as far as I know, `NSURLSession().dataTaskWithRequest(...)` can't throw. Is this correct and if so, is there some workaround? Or should I do something totally different?

Answer (score 1):

Since dataTaskWithRequest is an asynchronous operation, its error handling is facilitated with a completion handler. If it were to throw, it would be difficult to handle an error at the completion of the operation.

Therefore, you should handle the error condition within the completion handler. If you wanted to throw your own error upon completion, that would be possible but somewhat superfluous.

Comment: but how do I get back to the user then? This function can be called from a number of ViewControllers and I would like to display a message to the user that an error occurred without duplicating the code that checks whether an error occurred.

Comment: When an error occurs, you could call a separate error handling class that reports the error. The call could be made in one line and the logic for the error handling would not be repeated if it were in a separate class. You would likely have to let the error handler know of the view controller where the error is happening to present an error view.

Comment: but does the ViewController where I call `makeAPICall(..)` wait until `makeAPICall(..)` is finished before going to the next line? (I'm wondering because dataTaskWithRequest is asynchronous)

Comment: There is no waiting with an asynchronous request. That's why there's a completion handler, so you can do something when `makeAPICall` is complete. It either completes successfully or with an error.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of throwing an error, have your clients pass in a block, and run that block whenever the request fails (or, for that matter, when it completes successfully).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's indeed what I ended up doing, but it means calling closures within closures which is getting a bit complicated. So I was wondering if there would be other/better solutions.

Comment: I'll write my own answer once I finish this part of the project but haven't had time lately...

Answer (score 0):

Actually you you can handle the error if occurs. For instance

```
 let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                // do whatever you want, there is an error
            }
            if let data = data{
                print("data =\(data)")
            }
            if let response = response {
                print("url = \(response.URL!)")
                print("response = \(response)")
                let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
                print("response code = \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
            }
        })
```

and I showed you how to get the response code as well.

Comment: I get this, but my problem is that I need to report to the user if there is an error. So the caller of the `makeAPICall(..)` function (a `ViewController`) needs to know somehow whether an error occurred.

Comment: @Fr4nc3sc0NL you are making a HTTP request, the error that I showed you is an error in the HTTP request. If you mean that it is possible that the HTTP request succeeds (received to the server), but the server could return  a specific data indicates an error, then you can check the data (the HTTP response body) and validates your scenarios.

Comment: Actually I have to deal with both, and in both scenarios I have to report back to the user. (so maybe a better way to do this is to return data, response and error to the calling `ViewController` which can then call another method to determine whether an error occurred?)

Comment: @Fr4nc3sc0NL great, and you can do that. First in case of HTTP error. do what ever you want inside the `if let error...`, and then you can check the `http response data`, if, for example, your response data is json, validate the field `result` for true of false. and in case of false, handle the error.